# Escape back slash next to double quote in PowerShell failing

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch

I'm running PowerShell in a batch file to replace characters and I'm stuck trying to replace instances of `\"` with `"`.

`\` on its own can be escaped by doing `\\`

`"` on its own can be escaped by doing `""""`

Those work but if there's a back slash **next to** a double quote, this doesn't work: `\\""""`

Is it possible to do this, still using PowerShell in a batch file?

Comment: I'd have to see more of the PS logic you are working with in the batch file using the replace command, method, etc. but see if simply adding a a caret `^` before each character does the trick e.g. ``^\^\^"^"^"^"`` or otherwise try it with the backtick ` character instead of the caret `^` for the escape character. If that doesn't do it, share some of the batch running PowerShell logic.

Comment: Nothing I have tried has worked up to now. The full command is `start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) -replace '\\""""', '""""' | Set-Content $_.FullName}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `-Replace` operator works matching regex patterns, you can use the `[ ]` square bracket and put the escaped characters in two separate sets for the value to be escaped and replaced i.e. `'[\\][""]'`.

You can use `'""""'` for the single double quote replacement characters of the two to replace. So it's look like so basically: `(Get-Content $_) -replace '[\\][""]', '""""'`.

**Please note** that `-replace '[\\][""]', '""""'` assumes you want to replace `\"` with just `"` but you can change it to `-replace '[\\][""]', '#'` to replace `\"` with `#` like that if needed for example.

### Working Full Command Line Syntax

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) -replace '[\\][""]', '""""' | Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

**Troubleshooting detail...**

I used this syntax for a single file to start

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem 'C:\Folder\test.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) -replace '[\\][""]', '"""' }"
```

Once I ironed out at this level, I moved on to the full command and ran it against a single file still and kept checking it per each run until I figured out what was needed to get the final desired result.

### Supporting Resource

- [About Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1)

  > `-replace`
  > replaces strings matching a regex pattern

Comment: The key point is to use `'[\\][""]'` for the value of the first parameter of the `-replace` operator more than anything @bat_cmd. The replacement character is a matter of changing the second `-replace` operator parameter value with the single quotes. I wasn't sure if you were replacing `\"` with just `"` like that or not but trivial adjustments are easy enough there if you need further help. Also note I attempted to give you a solution that doesn't require much syntax change that what you were working with logic wise from your answer.

Comment: The perfect answer `'[\\][""]', '"""'` I thought this wouldn't be possible, cheers :) So the `[` and `]` when not being escaped, can have a useful purpose with powershell without messing up the batch file commands, I never realized that.

Comment: Liateral brackets, `[` & `]`, are troublesome in **PowerShell** *paths* because of the expanded definiton of [wildcards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.1) in **PowerShell**. But they're critical to regex syntax. Apples & oranges.